# Correct way to implmenet OAuth login in Quasar Framework

Tags: oauth, quasar

I've tried using `iframe` that works normally on facebook (but even with `:src.sync` attribute, the redirect Url cannot be captured), and it refused to display with google account:

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxx-yyy…enid+email+profile&state=zzz' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'
```

So i tried [Utils.openURL](http://quasar-framework.org/api/js-utils.html), but I didn't know is there any API to fetch the redirect URL response (unlike `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` on Android WebView or `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` on iOS WebView) inside the SPA.

What's the correct workaround for this?